How to get rid of both CS0022 and CS1503 using a multidimensional array
I am try to make a test to see all columns in rows in a array are the same number but I keep getting the following error:

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int[,]' to 'int[][]' CS1503

using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args){
       testing Test = new testing();
       
       if(Test.test(Test.array) == true){
           //code
       }
    }
    
}
class testing{
    public int[,] array = {{10,0,25,7},
                           {5,0,30,10}};
    public bool test(int[][] array){
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(1); i++){
            if(array[i][4] <= 0){
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count == array.GetLength(1);
    }
}

I tried to change test(int[][] array) to test(int[,] array) to get rid of the error but instead I get this error:

Wrong number of indices inside []; expected 2 CS0022

I already got two indices but the error highlights array[i].

int[][] and int[,] are different. You need to choose one of them and be consistent. If you choose [,] you need to change the access array[i][j] to array[i,j]. Also the name array might cause name conflicts, so you'd better change it.

Another issue is that array[i][4] goes out of bounds, because indices are zero based and so 4 is out of the range of 0..3.

There are some more issues in your code - posted a complete answer below.

There are several problematic issues in your code:

int[][] and int[,] are different. You need to choose one of them and be consistent.
I'll assume you picked int[,] for the rest of the answer, but it could be adapted to int[][].
When you access an int[,] element you should use operator[,] (not operator[][]) - so array[i][j] should be array[i,j].
Array indices are zero based, and so array[i][4] (even if you choose int[][]) will go out of bounds - the second index should be in the range 0..3.
Array dimensions are also zero based. In your outer loop you seem to attempt to iterate over the first dimension, so you have to use array.GetLength(0), not array.GetLength(1).
This is not causing an immediate error, but array is rather a bad name as it could cause conflicts, it is better to choose another name (e.g. arr).

A fixed version:
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        testing Test = new testing();

        if (Test.test(Test.arr) == true)
        {
            //code
        }
    }

}
class testing
{
    public int[,] arr = {{10,0,25,7},
                        {5,0,30,10}};
    public bool test(int[,] arr)
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            if (arr[i,3] <= 0)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count == arr.GetLength(0);
    }
}

Side notes:

You mentioned that you want to test if all columns in rows in a array are the same number. But the logic you posted is quite different.
Anyway based on the comments above you can modify the logic according to your needs.
Your test method code does not actually access the array member of class testing directly, but rather the method parameter (although in Main you pass the member as the argument).
Therefore you can either make it a static method (if you want to make it a free utility), or remove the array parameter so that the method will access the member.

